# How to set up chroot for jenkins build?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, chroot

I want to automate builds all in a chroot:

```
sudo chroot mychroot
apt-get install git build-essential make -y
git clone myrepo
cd myrepo/src
make
```

From this thread it seems my configuration in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System should be:

```
Name: trusty
Tool: pbuilder
Advanced configuration: checked
Additional arguments: --distribution trusty --debootstrapopts --variant=buildd

Shell command:
Repositories:
Name: universe
Repository URL: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
Keyfile URL: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/project/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I've also added jenkins into the `/etc/sudoers` file as discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/rmohr/chroot-plugin/issues/3).

Can anyone share their configuration?  The [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/chroot+Plugin) is great but I feel a bit lacking:

What is [described here](http://blog.steve.org.uk/continuous_integration_that_uses_chroots_.html) is exactly what I want:

```
Creates a new debootstrap-based chroot.
Installs build-essential, mercurial, etc.
Fetches the shource.
Runs make.
Copies the files produced in ./binary-out/ to a safe location.
Cleans up.
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is suitable to prepare a chroot in advance (say all jobs use the same configuration), then what you want can easily be achieved on an SSH slave by using the following configuration to /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the slave:

```
Match User jenkins
      ChrootDirectory /var/chroot/
      X11Forwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
```

When Jenkins log in to the slave over SSH to perform the build, he will automatically be thrown in to the chroot without the need to add Jenkins to sudoers, create a chroot, and install dependencies before the build magic can happen.

In cases where Jenkins will always be in the same chroot on a machine, this is a much simpler, not to mention less error-prone, route to take.

Comment: Good idea.  My build chroot is not yet stable however and would prefer to start from scratch every time as it evolves (and I want to be sure I'm not carrying over unknown artifacts.  I guess I could have a separate job to initialize the chroot, then when that one finishes, use the other job to jump into it directly.